# Searching an array for an element, and appending it to the end of the array if it isn't present

Tags: c++, arrays

It's a practice problem I'm trying to do, but so far I've had no luck. Here's what I tried so far:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  


string updateList(char arr[],char key, int n);

int main() 
{ 
    char usernames[10];
    int sizeOf = 2;
    usernames[0] = 'a'; usernames[1] = 'b';
    string x = updateList(usernames, 'c', sizeOf);
    cout << x;
}
string updateList(char arr[],char key, int n) 
{ 
    int arrLength = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char);
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == key) {
            return "Username already exists";}
        else {
            arr[n++] = key;
            int arrLength = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char);
            for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
                cout << arr[i];
                return "\n Username added";
             }
            
 } }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: array size is of 10 characters...it is fixed. I think it should be dynamic

Comment: You code won't compile. Please fix it.

Comment: In your case `sizeof(arr)` will not give you the size of the array. Better use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is known at compile time, or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if not

Comment: If you aren't locked with a C array you can use `std::vector` + https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Absolutely correct. There were some grave errors in my code, thank you for pointing them out @TedLyngmo

Comment: @Okabe_ Better - but you should turn on more compilation warnings to see more of the potential problems. Look here: https://godbolt.org/z/hfW8sY

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your approach is that you are not updating the value of n(sizeOf) and you are using n to add element which will create error.instead of that use pass by reference so that n(i,e here sizeOf will updated) will updated Try something like

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  


string updateList(char arr[],char key, int *n);

int main() 
{ 
    char usernames[10];
    int sizeOf=2;
    usernames[0] = 'a'; usernames[1] = 'b';
    string x = updateList(usernames, 'c', &sizeOf);
    cout << x;

int updateList(char arr[],char key, int n) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == key) {
            return "Username already exists";}
        else {
            arr[n++] = key;
            for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
                cout << arr[i];
             }
            
    return 0; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use string or vector in order to keep the array of chars dynamic. This is an example of string and it also acts as an array of characters.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    string usernames="ab";
    char key = 'b';
    int i=0;
    for(;i<usernames.size();i++)
        if(usernames[i]==key)
        {
            printf("Key exists already");
            break;
        }
    if(i==usernames.size())
    {
          usernames.push_back(key);
          cout << usernames <<endl;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```